# In React w/ Redux a new element disappears about a second after it initially renders

Tags: javascript, react-redux

Hi guys I am making a small app in react and redux and I have a very annoying bug. I think is working ok and I don't get any error in the console but when I try to render out a new element it disappears after one second and I have no idea why. If anyone has any clues as to why I would greatly appreciate it.

```
my actions
const BookActions = () => {
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');
const dispatch = useDispatch();

 return (
 <form>
  <h2 className="addbook">ADD NEW BOOK</h2>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Book Title"
    onChange={(event) => {
      setTitle(event.target.value);
    }}
   />
   <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Author"
    onChange={(event) => {
      setAuthor(event.target.value);
    }}
    />
     <button
      onClick={() => {
      dispatch(
        addBook({
          id: 0,
          title: title,
          author: author,
          compleated: false,
          chapter: 1,
        })
       );
       }}
      className="bookbtn"
      type="submit"
       >
      Add Book
      </button>
     </form>
     );
     };`

     export const bookSlice = createSlice({
     name: 'books',
     initialState: { value: BookList },
      reducers: {
      addBook: (state, action) => {
      state.value.push(action.payload);
      },
      },
      });

      my store

      const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
      books: bookReducer,
      },
      });
      const root = 
      ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
      root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
     <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
      </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </React.StrictMode>
```

Comment: The code you included is way too incomplete to be able to help you. I suggest you create a fully reproducible example of the bug on codesandbox. You should also install the React and Redux devtools and try to debug it yourself, saying "the element disappears" is way too vague to be able to help you.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie thanks for the advice I have React and Redux devtools but there are no errors that's my problem and I don't see any problems in  the code

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using a `<form>` element the form is submitting when you click the button. To prevent this happening you need to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in the click handler.

Alternatively remove the `<form>` element - the inputs/button don't require it. It depends if you're going to introduce any [client-side form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) in which case you *should* keep it and use the aforementioned solution.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');

  return (
    <form>
      <h2 className="addbook">ADD NEW BOOK</h2>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Book Title"
        onChange={(event) => {
          setTitle(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Author"
        onChange={(event) => {
          setAuthor(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log('Submitted');
          // dispatch();
        }}
        className="bookbtn"
        type="submit"
      >Add Book
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```